# Update data in simple D3.js doughnut chart with animation

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I playing around with simple D3.js chart. Previously I updated it by removing SVG group and create new chart. I want to change it to update paths after new data will come without removing svg. However, its not updating it and I have no idea what I doing wrong. [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w5v9nza4/2/)

JS

```
var update_counter = 0;
function drawChart() {
    var pie_d = 185,
        r = pie_d / 2,
        pieData = [1, Math.random() * 10],
        pie = d3.layout.pie(),
        arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(60).outerRadius(r);

    update_counter++;
    if (!document.querySelectorAll('.svg svg').length) {
        d3.select('.svg').append('svg:svg')
            .data([pieData])
            .attr('width', pie_d)
            .attr('height', pie_d);
    } else {
        d3.select('.svg svg')
            .data([pieData]);
    }
    var arcs = d3.select('.svg svg').selectAll('g')
        .data(pie)
        .enter().append('svg:g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + r + ',' + r + ')');

    arcs.append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', arc)
        .attr('class', function (d, i) {
            return i === 0 ? 'onl' : 'ter'
        });
    d3.select('.counter').text(update_counter);
}
drawChart();
setInterval(function () {
    drawChart()
}, 5000);
```

**UDPATE**

Nearly there but still sometimes animation 'jump' [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w5v9nza4/3/)

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410)?

Comment: Thank you for that, It's really helpful but now I have problem with animation - sometimes it's just randomly jumping fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w5v9nza4/3/